# iOS7 background fetch EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, background, fetch

I'm trying to implement a background fetch method to get new data, but it's giving me an error with an NSMutable Dictionary.  Here's my code

In my appDelegate under performFetchWithCompletionHandler I have:

```
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*) self.window.rootViewController;

id topViewController = navigationController.topViewController;

if ([topViewController isKindOfClass:[viewController class]])
{
    [(viewController*)topViewController autologin];
}
else
{
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

This calls auto login in my view controller

```
- (void) autologin
{

NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString* username = [defaults valueForKey:@"username"];

NSString* password = [defaults valueForKey:@"password"];

[self login:username password:password];
}
```

Which then calls login

```
- (void)login:(NSString*)username password:(NSString*) password
{
NSDictionary *login = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:username, @"username", password, @"password", NO, @"showNotification", nil];

NSOperationQueue* backgroundQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];

ch = [[backgroundProcess alloc] init];

NSInvocationOperation* operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:ch selector:@selector(runEvents:) object:login];

[backgroundQueue addOperation:operation];

operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(checkStatus) object:nil];

[backgroundQueue addOperation:operation];
}
```

Everything works if my app is running in the foreground and I call the login function, but with the performFetchWithCompletionHandler as soon as it hits

```
NSDictionary *login = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:username, @"username", password, @"password", NO, @"showNotification", nil];
```

I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can put NO in a dictionary? Wouldn't you need `[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]`?

Comment: I think you can use @NO also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are only crashing from the background. One error I see is that you can't use "NO" (a scalar BOOLEAN value) in a dictionary directly. NSDictionary objects can only contain objects. You need to convert the NO value to an NSNumber. With recent versions of Objective C you can use the syntax @(NO) to convert a scalar to an NSNumber. This is the equivalent of

```
[NSNumber numberWithBool: NO];
```

I doubt if that is the source of your crash, but it is an error in your code.

I don't know the object ownership rules of NSInvocationOperation off the top of my head. Since the introduction of GCD I haven't used NSOperations or NSOperationQueues. You might want to think about using GCD based calls instead.

Comment: This was definitely it.  Super strange that it only affected running in the background though.  Thanks!